# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'from_tensorflow_frozen_model'

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia, tensorrt

I am trying to convert my PB model to tenrorrt uff model to make it work on tx2.

I used the example code from the Nvidia forum and tried to execute it. 
I know it is some python package related issue but I am not able to solve it

I get following error with the below code

```js
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

    import tensorrt as trt
    from tensorrt.parsers import uffparser


    import pycuda.driver as cuda
    import pycuda.autoinit
    import numpy as np
    from random import randint # generate a random test case
    from PIL import Image
    from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow #to show test case
    import time #import system tools
    import os

    import uff

    uff_model = uff.from_tensorflow_frozen_model('./rcnn_3chan.pb', ['image_tensor','detection_scores','detection_boxes' ,'detection_classes' ,'num_detections'])

    parser.register_output("image_tensor")
    parser.register_output("detection_scores")
    parser.register_output("detection_boxes")
    parser.register_output("detection_classes")
    parser.register_output("num_detections")
```

```python
    WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py:198: retry (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.base) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
    Instructions for updating:
    Use the retry module or similar alternatives.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "uff.py", line 5, in <module>
        import tensorrt as trt
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorrt/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
        from tensorrt import infer, parsers, utils, lite, plugins
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorrt/utils/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
        from ._utils import *
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorrt/utils/_utils.py", line 59, in <module>
        import uff
      File "/home/fts/Downloads/Amruta/uff.py", line 20, in <module>
        uff_model = uff.from_tensorflow_frozen_model('./rcnn_3chan.pb', ['image_tensor','detection_scores','detection_boxes' ,'detection_classes' ,'num_detections'])
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'from_tensorflow_frozen_model'
```

My env Variables:

```js
    export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/:/home/fts/Downloads/TensorRT-3.0.4/lib
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/fts/Downloads/TensorRT-3.0.4/lib
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64:/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64:/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    export CUDA_ROOT=/usr/local/cuda-9.0
    export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
    export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-9.0
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record (new to Python)
I had named my py file name as uff